# Как считать кириллицу с screen.getch() в curses (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, кириллица, curses

Я делаю чат на python 3 с curses. Проблема в том, что, пытаясь ввести что нибудь русской раскладкой, я получаю лишь набор непонятных символов юникода.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import curses
from curses import wrapper

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.UTF8")
# Не помогло, но решил на всякий случай оставить

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.line = 0
        self.buffer = ""
        self.updated = False

    def init(self, screen):

        # Первичная настройка curses
        curses.curs_set(False)
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.noecho()
        screen.nodelay(1)
        screen.bkgd(' ')
        screen.keypad(True)

        self.msg_pad = curses.newpad(1000, 100) # Интересно, что произойдёт, если
                                                # ввести более 1000 сообщений?

        for y in range(1000):
            self.msg_pad.addstr(y, 5, "Hello, World! (#%i)" % y)
            # Типо сообщения других пользователей

    def main(self, screen):
        self.init(screen)
        while True:
            self.msg_pad.refresh(self.line, 0, 1, 1, int(curses.LINES/2), 75)
            k = screen.getch() # Возвращает что-то непонятное при попытке ввести русские буквы
                               # При том английские буквы работают нормально

            if k == curses.KEY_UP:
                if self.line > 0: self.line -= 1
            elif k == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                if self.line < 999: self.line += 1
            # Скроллинг

            elif k == ord('\n'): # Enter
                # Здесь мы отправляем то, что мы ввели на сервер.
                # На самом деле это не код чата, а такая себе песочница, где
                # я пытаюсь реализовать нормальный интерфейс.
                # Так что никаких сокетов)
                self.buffer = ""
                self.updated = True

            elif k == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE:
                self.buffer = self.buffer[0:len(self.buffer)-1]
                self.updated = True

            elif k != -1: # -1 - то, что возвращает getch(), если нет ввода
                self.updated = True
                self.buffer += chr(k) # Кажется, это не лучший способ, ну да ладно

            curses.update_lines_cols() # Если пользователь изменил размер окна, нужно
                                       # обновить curses.LINES и curses.COLS,
                                       # иначе будет плохо.

            screen.addstr(curses.LINES-2, 2, ">>> "+self.buffer) # Отображаем ввод

            screen.refresh()
            if self.updated:
                self.updated = False
                screen.clear()
                # Если постоянно обновлять экран, он лагает.
                # А так все оптимально.

wrapper(App().main)
```

[image: Screenshot]
Вот что выходит.

Я подозреваю, что при считывании русских символов, curses думает, что у меня какая то другая раскладка. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: getch читает один байт, а русские символы занимают два байта. Анлгийский Stack Overflow [подсказывает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375235) использовать get_wch

Comment: @andreymal, помогло, спасибо)